# SQL Parent Child - Master Grandparent Hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child, hierarchy

I have a table called LIST in the following format where in each row parents and childs are identified. There are multiple levels of childs 
[Current: Before hierarchical order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6JNE.png)

I need to transform this table and write to a new table with the format showcased below. Assigning a Unique ID to each Name so it could be sorted in a hierarchical order as follows:

[After hierarchical order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHU78.png)

Can anyone guide me in the right direction of how to go about this programmatically?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
create table hierarchy (Parent varchar(3), child varchar(10))

insert into hierarchy values
('A','AB')
,('A','AC')
,('A','AD')
,('A','AE')
,('AB','ABC')
,('AB','ABD')
,('AB','ABE')
,('ABC','ABCD')
,('ABC','ABCE')
GO

; WITH cte_Hierarchy
AS
(
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [name]) Id
    , t.[name]
FROM(
    SELECT Parent [name] FROM hierarchy t
    UNION
    SELECT child FROM hierarchy t
)t
)
SELECT t.Id
        , t.[name]
        , h.Parent
        , p.Id ParentId
FROM cte_Hierarchy t
LEFT JOIN hierarchy h ON h.child = t.[name]
LEFT JOIN cte_Hierarchy p on p.[name] = h.Parent
```